# JSONDecodeError when trying to write file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a simple geoJSON file and dump it into a more legible format...

```
import json

filename = 'usgs_earthquakes_today.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)
    
readable_file = 'readable_eq_data_today.json'
with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)
```

The traceback returns:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b742605a3e92> in <module>
      5 filename = 'usgs_earthquakes_today.json'
      6 with open(filename) as f:
----> 7     all_eq_data = json.load(f)
      8 
      9 readable_file = 'readable_eq_data_today.json'
```

Unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Because the file doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: might want to try [https://pypi.org/project/geojson/](https://pypi.org/project/geojson/)

Comment: I just solved the problem by closing the JSON file in my web browser. Is it common with Python that accessing open files is problematic?